# Set my program files to a different drive, and then removed that drive. Can't install programs anymore

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, windows-registry

I set my program files directory to H:\Program Files\ via regedit at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion
DWORDS: ProgramFilesDir, ProgramFilesDir (x86)

Then, I removed the H:\ drive from my computer a good 3 months later.

Windows automatically changed the DWORDs back to the default C:\ drive location, but programs still are expecting H:\ and I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: search in the registry for all other H:\ entries and change them back to C:\

Comment: There's hundreds of entries, it would take me ages. Any automated way to do this?

Comment: In regedit use ctrl+f to search and hit F3 to 'find next'.  It might take a while, otherwise you will probably have to write a python or powershell script to get what you want.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24209343/how-to-get-all-the-windows-registry-entries

Comment: There are better registry editors that will allow you to search faster, present all results together and allow you to replace all, but you should be extremely cautious when doing this or you're liable to end up with a completely hosed install.